# Text selection tools in ActionBar are white on white background after selecting text in Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-actionbar, android-dialogfragment, textselection

Anyone had this issue, that after selecting text in dialog's EditText, toolbar appears with invisible action buttons (white on white background)?

How do I set theme to a DialogFragment?

[image: Can't see text selection tools in action bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can custom dialog theme in styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog" />
```

then use `MyDialogTheme` in your `DialogFragment`

**UPDATE**

In your dialog use following codes to set custom theme:

```
ContextThemeWrapper context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.MyDialogTheme);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
... ...
```

Comment: Setting style with `dialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyDialogTheme);` does not give any effect. :(